# How do you structure a term paper that involves comparing journal articles?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

As part of a course on statistics and stochastic processes, I have to read 3-4 journal articles and write a paper explaining and comparing them and explaining my learnings from them as they relate to the course. Can anyone give any advice on how to structure it or a general approach to follow, or provide examples of such papers on any topic I can use as a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already showed a structure, which I find convincing for your situation:

- introduction
- (short) summary, what each article is about (with 3-4 subsections, i.e. 1 per article)
- what‘s same, similar, different (probably you won‘t need all 4 over 2 = 6 combinations as subsections; do clever comparison)
- what you learned from them
- how they relate to your course
- summary
- bibliography (at least the articles)
- glossary, if needed
- appendix, if needed

Length, hence depths, may vary. If you don‘t have any requirements to follow, sth. like 4-6 pages letter or A4 seems to be a reasonable target.

Some tools:

- be focused on what‘s relevant to your reader: if in doubt, cut information i.e. length
- tables are a good way to compare and present differences and commonalities
- write a first version quickly; allow 1 or a few days to put it aside; then review, rewrite, finalize
- it may be a good idea to discuss both concept and progress with sb else.

---

**P.S.**: A few add-ons.

1. When searching for structure of term papers (refine as needed), the first hit says:

*THE SECTIONS OF A TERM PAPER
Adhere to guidelines and requirements based on your course and instructor. The most conventional structure of a term paper follows the above order: 1) introduction; 2) theory chapter(s); 3) analysis, and 4) conclusion.*

2. [How to write a term paper](https://essaypro.com/blog/term-paper) goes into some more detail.
3. So does the [Guide on How to Write a Term Paper](https://essayshark.com/blog/a-quick-start-guide-on-how-to-write-a-term-paper/).

Comment: I suggest replacing the closing "summary" with a "discussion" in which you draw a conclusion from your observations. Also, put an abstract at the beginning of the paper in which you briefly (150 to 250 words) summarize what you did and what the results are. In the introduction, explain why you are doing what you are doing and how this is relevant.